# Breadthfirst layout of parents, not child nodes

Tags: layout, nested, nodes, cytoscape.js

I'm interested in creating a graph of parent nodes each containing 1 or more child nodes to be placed via co-ordinates. Child nodes will have edges to other child nodes in the graph.

I would then like to perform a breadthfirst layout on the parents, without disturbing the local position of the child nodes.

[image]

Is this possible in Cytoscape.js? Will I need to write a custom layout module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compound nodes don't really have independent positions and dimensions:  A parent is wholly dependent on children for to fit its position and dimensions.

To do what you suggest, you'd need to move all the descendants of a parent to effectively move the parent.  For that, you'd need unique layout logic.

You could probably just use the [scaffolder](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/autoscaffolding) and copy the [`breadthfirst`](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/v2.6.9/src/extensions/layout/breadthfirst.js) code as a basis -- modifying it for what you need.  If you want to have it public, it could be a nice layout extension in the [listing](http://js.cytoscape.org/#extensions/layout-extensions).

Comment: but is it possible to somehow render a completely independent graph inside a node? possibly using a (well performing/scaling) hack, such as rendering a Cytoscape.js graph inside a Cytoscape.js graph node.

Comment: Render the other graph in another instance.  Generate an image from the graph and use that as a background image on a node in the first instance.

Comment: that's a nice idea; probably able to perform too